# Magento 2: Changing Price of Product in Controller doesn't work at the moment!

Tags: magento2, module, cart, price, extensions

I tried to change the Price of my Products like this:

> Controller.php:

[EDIT]

```
   <?php

namespace MassiveArt\ShoppingCart\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey;

class Index extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var FormKey
     */
    protected $formKey;

    /**
     * @var Session
     */
    protected $checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @var Cart
     */
    protected $cart;

    /**
     * @var ProductFactory
     */
    protected $productFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @param Context                         $context
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param JsonFactory                     $resultJsonFactory
     * @param FormKey                         $formKey
     * @param Cart                            $cart
     * @param ProductFactory                  $productFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        FormKey $formKey,
        Cart $cart,
        ProductFactory $productFactory
    ) {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->formKey = $formKey;
        $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        try {

            // Set result data and pass back
            $result = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();


            $allItems = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
            foreach ($allItems as $item) {
                $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
                $price = 100; //set your price here
                $item->setCustomPrice($price);
                $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
                $item->setSubtotal($price);
                $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
            }
            $this->checkoutSession->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false);
            $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->save();
            $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false);
            $this->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false);

            $result->setData(['message' => __("Products added succesfully")]);

            return $result;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $result->setData(['error' => __($e->getMessage())]);
            return $result;
        }
    }
}
```

(EDIT)
With the new code the price changes, but the subtotal not! As you can see here:
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate? which controller do you use, and what is your task? Do you want to change the price when a customer adds a product to the cart?

Comment: Hello Sony, no i want to change the price, if a button is clicked, not if a product is getting added to cart. For now i just want to change the price of all products to 100$ for testing. I will update my question to show you some more code

Comment: Sorry, I am afraid to not understand what you are trying. When I look at your code, you look to want to change the prices of items which are in your basket. Indeed you are calling the `quote` from the `checkoutSession` . I am a bit confused.

Comment: Yes I want to change the prices of the items in my basket. I tried some other stuff as well to achieve this and the last one I tried is the current code with quote.

Comment: The price change will not work using the controller you need to use plugin or observer for that.

Comment: but why should there not be any possiblity to change the price in the controller?

Comment: you can change price change when product add to cart?

Comment: no I can't as the price should be changed if a button in the cart is clicked, therefore the product was added to the cart before the price is changing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I get it, I think you are in the right way, but I think you have to save the quote. If you take a look on this class :
`\Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add`
you can see at Line 114 :

```
$this->cart->addProduct($product, $params);
            if (!empty($related)) {
                $this->cart->addProductsByIds(explode(',', $related));
            }

            $this->cart->save();
```

I change the price from the event which is called at the end of the `addProduct()` method, and Magento saves the cart at the end.
So in your case, you have to save the quote in your controller.

Comment: Ok, Price gets changed now (look at my updated Question), but the subtotal wont change, any ideas?

Comment: also if you then click on checkout, the price is the same again

Comment: I think you have to take a look on the Quote Model, especially at the collectTotals() method. You have to set the flag $this->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false) which ask to Magento to calculate again.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me :(

Comment: Tried it in a lot of different ways and it never worked.

Comment: Any other ideas, what I could try to do?

Comment: can you post your code about the `collectTotals()` ?

Comment: Yes I updated my Question

Comment: you applied the `setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)` to the `checkoutSession`. If you take a look at the quote model, this should be applied to the `quote model`, not for the `checkoutSession`

Comment: does not work as well

Answer (score 3):

I did a snippet which allows you to change the price. Actually, it changes the price after you add product in your basket. In other words, it changes the prices of your items in your quote.
https://gist.github.com/0-Sony/d9d2ea792b5533bfeaff28827e6f207a

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry it does not help, i cant use an observer, i need to use my controller

Answer (score 3):

You want to update the row total and not the subtotal, use method `$item->setRowTotal()` or `$item->setBaseRowTotal()`.
Also, it might help to add `$item->save()` before the end of the loop.

Subtotal is the order/cart subtotal.

Comment: Unfortunately this changed nothing. But thanks for your answer

Answer (score 3):

@felix,You need to set `setSubtotal()` for a quote. Set Subtotal outside f`or loop`.

```
$subTotal = $cart->getQuote()->setSubtotal($price);
$this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->save();
```

like this

```
foreach ($allItems as $item) {
                $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
                $price = 100; //set your price here
                $item->setCustomPrice($price);
                $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
                $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
            }
            $subtotalprice=100;
            $subTotal = $cart->getQuote()->setSubtotal($subtotalprice);
            $this->checkoutSession->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false);
            $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->save();
```

**Note: Code Tested**

Comment: May worked for you, but not for me.

Comment: Did you try this( $subTotal = $cart->getQuote()->setSubtotal($subtotalprice);) outside this for loop

Comment: yes, i did this exactly how you said

Comment: setSubtotal is only not working. correct? other set methods working fine like setprice ? correct?

Comment: Yes correct....

Answer (score 3):

For Upadate cart price you have to use Model cart instead checkout session.
Load item from cart and update it.

```
<?php 
$items = $this->cart->getQuote()->getAllItems(); //Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart
foreach($items as $item) {

    $item = $this->cart->getQuote()->getItemById($item->getId());
    if (!$item) {
      continue;
    }

    $price = 100;
    $item->setCustomPrice($price);
    $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
    $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    $item->save();           
}
$this->cart->save();
?>
```

Comment: Actually it is not working, sorry

Comment: It's my working code,i'm creating Quote by custom price by API.It must Work.may be any module conflicts your side

Answer (score 0):

**Try below code:**

you need to modify `process()` function for your requirement.

> vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/Validator.php

```
/**
     * Quote item discount calculation process
     *
     * @param AbstractItem $item
     * @return $this
     */
    public function process(AbstractItem $item)
    {
        $item->setDiscountAmount(0);
        $item->setBaseDiscountAmount(0);
        $item->setDiscountPercent(0);
        $itemPrice = $this->getItemPrice($item);
        if ($itemPrice < 0) {
            return $this;
        }

        $appliedRuleIds = $this->rulesApplier->applyRules(
            $item,
            $this->_getRules($item->getAddress()),
            $this->_skipActionsValidation,
            $this->getCouponCode()
        );
        $this->rulesApplier->setAppliedRuleIds($item, $appliedRuleIds);
        /*Your custom code START here*/
        $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
        $price = 499; //set your price here
        $item->setCustomPrice($price);
        $item->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
        $item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
        //echo "sku: ".$item->getSku()."=== Name: ".$item->getName();die;
        /* Your custom code END here */
        return $this;
    }
```

**NOTE:** Don't modify magento core files. Create plugin for this.

**I hope it will help...!!!**

Comment: But if I create a plugin for this and one other extension, which runs on the same store, also creates a plugin of the Validator.php only one will be working. true?

Comment: @felix : No, you just need to create plugin for process function of validator.php file. it will run for your all stores.first you just make change in core file and check once your requirement is fulfil or not? If all are okay with this modification then after you create plugin for this.

Comment: Ok, will try this tomorrow and will then give you a reply.

Comment: This only changed the Price in the summary of the cart, but the price of the products just stay the same